# Nginx working as reverse proxy with backend on php-fpm always returns status code 200

Tags: php, nginx, php-7, alpine-linux, nginx-reverse-proxy

Whenever php server returns a response with body, nginx responds with status code 200 and the correct body from the application even when application does not returns with status code 200. If application does not set and response body, then nginx returns the same status code as returned by the application.

I'm using this Dockerfile.

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine3.9

RUN apk update && apk add nginx

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN mkdir -p /run/nginx

# nginx conf
RUN echo '\
server {                                                                \
    listen 80 default_server;                                           \
    listen [::]:80 default_server;                                      \
                                                                        \
    location / {                                                        \
      # Remove trailing slashes before checking for matching locations  \
      rewrite ^(.+)\/$ $1 permanent;                                    \
                                                                        \
      dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;                           \
      dav_access all:r;                                                 \
      index index.php index.html index.htm;                             \
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;                            \
    }                                                                   \
                                                                        \
    location ~ index\.php$ {                                            \
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;                                \
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;                         \
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;                                      \
      fastcgi_index index.php;                                          \
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;  \
    }                                                                   \
}                                                                       \
' > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;

# php file
RUN echo '\
<?php                             \
echo "Hello World";               \
http_response_code(400);          \
?>                                \
'> /var/www/html/index.php

ENTRYPOINT [ "ash" ]
```

For testing go inside running docker container

1. Start nginx
2. start php-fpm process
3. use curl for creating request
4. check nginx output log

```
$ nginx && \
  php-fpm --daemonize && \
  curl -XGET 127.0.0.1/abcd && \
  cat /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

NOTE: If you remove the **echo "Hello World";** from index.php, nginx returns the correct status code.

EDIT:

But this works as expected.

```
FROM debian:10-slim

ARG VERSION=7.2

# replace shell with bash so we can source files
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive NODE_VERSION=12

ADD https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg /opt/apt-php.gpg

RUN set -ex; \
    apt-get update -y; \
    apt-get install git gnupg -y; \
    apt-key add - < /opt/apt-php.gpg; \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates; \
    echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list; \
    apt-get update -y; \
    apt-get upgrade -y; \
    apt-get install -y \
    php${VERSION} \
    php${VERSION}-fpm \
    nginx \
    curl;

# nginx conf
RUN echo '\
server {                                                                \
    listen 80 default_server;                                           \
    listen [::]:80 default_server;                                      \
                                                                        \
    location / {                                                        \
      # Remove trailing slashes before checking for matching locations  \
      rewrite ^(.+)\/$ $1 permanent;                                    \
                                                                        \
      dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;                           \
      dav_access all:r;                                                 \
      index index.php index.html index.htm;                             \
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;                            \
    }                                                                   \
                                                                        \
    location ~ index\.php$ {                                            \
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;                                \
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;                         \
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;                                      \
      fastcgi_index index.php;                                          \
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;  \
    }                                                                   \
}                                                                       \
' > /etc/nginx/sites-available/default;

# php file
RUN echo '\
<?php                             \
echo "Hello World";               \
http_response_code(400);          \
?>                                \
'> /var/www/html/index.php

RUN sed -i "s/listen\ =\ \/run\/php\/php7.2-fpm.sock/listen\ =\ 127.0.0.1:9000/"  /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

RUN mkdir -p /run/php

RUN ln -s /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.2 /usr/sbin/php-fpm

ENTRYPOINT [ "bash" ]
```

Comment: I understand that echo(ing) something before setting the header information will actually send the response with no headers and status code due to which nginx will return with code 200. But is there a way to avoid that ?
Ref:- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Yes there is a way, using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php

Comment: Thanks. This actually worked. But i'm still confused why alpine based image (mentioned in question) didn't respected my output_buffering=4098 setting in ini file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behaviour as one can see here - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Specifically

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by > normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error 
>   to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access 
>   function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is 
>   called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

This can be avoided by setting **output_buffering** to On in php ini settings or running php cli with the option like `php -S localhost:5000 -d output_buffering=4098`.